# ASP.NET Controls are not dynamically added to the panel on page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net

In asp.net project, I am trying to add controls to the panel in C# on a button click event

When I put a debugger breakpoint then I can see the item being added but when the page is shown on the browser, the panel is emptyu.

I've tried adding !Page.PostBack but still no luck.

Am I missing something?

> protected void Test(object sender,
>   DirectEventArgs e)
>           {
>
> ```
>             Panel configurationPanel = new Panel();
>             configurationPanel.Title = "My Added Panel";
>
>             configurationPanel.Height = 100;
>
>
>             pnlInfo.Items.Add(configurationPanel);
>
>
>     }
> ```

Hits the break point and pnlInfo.Items.Count = 1 but it does not show on the page.

Comment: can you show us your code? how you have added your control?

Comment: Yes, ASP.Net + update panel + javascript

Answer (score 0):

did u try

```
  pnlInfo.Controls.Add(configurationPanel);
```

Comment: post ur aspx and aspx.cs code here... try using 'PlaceHolder' instead Panel, Check this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)